# Express Handlebars layout in layout

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

How can I paste layout "common" into home.

### dirs

layouts/
   ---- home.handlebars
   ---- common.handlebars
partials/
 ---- partial.handlebars
 index.handlebars
 page2.handlebars

### home.handlebars

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> poject </title>
</head>

<body>
    {{{ common }}} //layout common.handlebars
</body>
</html>
```

### common.handlebars

```
<header></header>
   {{{ body }}} // linked to index.handlebars
<footer></footer>
```